# PHP: Find out variable value with minimal evaluation

Tags: php, yii

I'm writing a plugin for my editor to support the Yii framework.
To make this plugin work I need to find out 2 paths from `index.php`: the
framework and configuration paths.

The usual `index.php` (which is the entry point for Yii) looks like this:

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../../usr/share/php-libs/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Basically I need to get list of required files and arguments for `Yii::createWebApplication()`.

But the code here can be anything. Literally anything. So is it possible to run this file somehow up to `Yii::createWebApplication()` so I could find out where the application directory is and where the framework is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Yii::app()->basePath* to get the root path of the application, and *Yii::app()->baseUrl* to get the relative URL for the application.

The Yii framework must to be in root htdocs of the Apache.

Comment: To get Yii::app() I must first evaluate index.php file. The problem is I don't want to do this because there can be anything. ATM I have solution modifyng copy of index.php. It works, but hardly its a good idea.

Comment: You can use $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] and $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] (with dirname()) for relatives path. The DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant is a good practice to use.

Comment: I found something. This echo realpath('/windows/system32'); prints "C:\WINDOWS\System32".

Comment: I don't have actual request. I'm doing static code analysis. I don't have web request, I don't know where project is deployed, I don't know is there any apache/nginx/whatever server...

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand wich file u are trying to get. You want to get files from Yii Framework? Or the application? wich files?

Comment: The idea is I have some PHP file. To check is it Yii app. I'm scanning *.php files in current file directory and up to / for createWebApplication. In case when some file matches I need to get pathes to: 1. framework itself and 2. actual application path (what's passed to createWebApplication). For thsi I can use only static code analysis or some partly evaluating approach that I'm looking for.

Comment: The user must difine the root directory of application, and the file in the root must be a index pre-defined of Yii. After you need to find the Yii Framework path, so you go forward one or two directory and make a recursive search for the Yii Framework.